# Sufficient criteria for the spectrum of a bounded operator to be convex.

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be an operator on some (separable) Hilbert space. If the Hilbert space is for example $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ and I consider the discrete Laplacian $\Delta$. Then $\sigma(\Delta) = \lbrack 0, 2d \rbrack$. This is a convex set.
Similarly, if I take the Hilbert space $L^2 \left( \lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \right)$ I can look at the operator that takes $(M_x f)(x) = x f(x)$. Then $\sigma(M_x) = \lbrack 0,1 \rbrack$ which is also convex.
These are just some example, but is there some theory which investigates whether the spectrum of a (not necessarily normal) operator $A$ is convex?

Comment: I can think of a characterization of *connected* spectra.  My guess would be that convex ones cannot be easily characterized.

Comment: Okay - do you have a reference for connected spectra?

Comment: It is not hard to prove that the spectrum of $T$ is disconnected iff the unital Banach algebra generated by $T$ contains a nontrivial idempotent.

Comment: Wait: I am talking about spectra of operators and not of rings. Is it the same?

Comment: There is a strong relationship between the spectrum of an operator and that of the algebra it generates.  The best result says that if $T$ is a bounded, self-adjoint operator than the spectrum of the closed algebra generated by $\{T,I\}$ is homeomorphic to the spectrum of $T$.  If $T$ is not self-adjoint then the result is not as nice but it is sufficient to prove the fact I mentioned about non-trivial idempotents.